# XSL-FO Table fixed height

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to generate a pdf file by using XSL-FO with FOP.

I want to display a table with a fixed height. The table can go on several pages and I would like it to have the same height on every pages.

I can't even seem to define a fixed height for the table on a single page.

I've tried setting the height, min-height, max-height on the table and table-body but nothing seems to be taken into account. I've also tried using different XSL-FO processors without any luck.

Small sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="20mm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="10mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" height="10cm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.02cm">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="60%"/>
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>Col1</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>Col2</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>Col3</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does the number of rows vary?

Comment: Yes... And the height of each one of them too... if there's breaklines in them.

Answer (score 2):

In `FOP` you need to work on the `<fo:table-cell` individually, for heights, font-size...etc.
You need to do the following:

1. Take your notes on the space you will provide for the table for each
   page
2. Calculate the number of rows of the table that can be fitted in that
   space
3. In a loop create a new table for each page providing the number of
   rows that each page would hold
4. Keep in mind hat the header of the table would only be constructed
   for the first page only, and the tables of the other pages must
   be constructed headlessly